# v-for exceeds the number of iterations 3x times

Tags: vue.js, for-loop, vue-component

I have a simple loop to list videos and a method that accepts each videos and calculates the price.The problem is the method is called 9 times while there are 3 elements in the looop.
I have an array containing videos named videos

```
> <li v-bind:key="video.video_id" v-for="video in videos">{{video.Name}}
> Price:{{PriceCalc(video)}}</li>
```

And the method just logs for now

```
PriceCalc(video){
console.log(video.video_id);}
```

this is called 9 times while the videos array only has 3 elements

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: Could you add your `videos` array ?

Comment: videos:[{Name:"somevideo",video_id:"1",videoType:"Regular"},{Name:"somevideo2",video_id:"2",videoType:"children"},{Name:"somevideo3",video_id:"3",videoType:"Regular"}]

Comment: https://codepen.io/disfated/pen/zYrGmQG
works ok

Comment: In your codepen, `PriceCalc` only gets called 3 times, once for each item.

Answer (score 0):

This simply has to do with change detection. Whenever change detection happens, `PriceCalc` is executed. Avoid calling methods in template, **especially** in a v-for. You can use a `computed` property usually, but being a v-for, it isn't suitable. I assume `PriceCalc` is supposed to calculate something, I suggest you handle that calculation in the script, before displaying it in template, depending on how you are getting data, do it in a suitable vue hook or after data has been received (if coming from API). Something like:

```
this.videos.forEach(video => {
   video.price = // here do your calculation!
})
```

Then you can display the value in the template simply by `{{ video.price }}` inside your `v-for`.